# mobile usability issues with /wp-content/uploads/ folders

Tags: seo

Google webmaster tools is telling me I have mobile usability issues with my wp-content/uploads/ folders.

These urls aren't for public viewing so it doesn't matter if there are issues but will I get penalised by Google for this?  Is there anything I can do about it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Shortly - It matter now, and you will get penalized.
Long story:
You should give more details, at least an url where the error comes... There is huge possibility you'll get penalized for that, as the new Google update require access to files that were ok to be blocked until now. For example - blocked .css or .js from Robots.txt that is in the wp-content directory could hurt your mobile usability. For that you get direct penalty by the last mobilegeddon update, as the resources blocked by robots.txt and are vital for the page rendering are preventing the googlebot to see that page as mobile friendly.

Comment: Actually everything I've read since posting here suggests that only pages that have mobile usability issues will be penalised rather than the whole site.  Its possible that this will have a knock on effect to overall site ranking but as the wp-content/uploads/ folder isn't indexed anyway it shouldn't matter. too much.  So thanks for your answer, but I disagree!

Comment: I never said your whole site will get penalized, it's true, it's page based, and it will penalize only the pages not optimized, and only in the mobile search. However webmaster tools shows you not that wp-content folder have issues, but rather the page it's giving you have issues because of wp-content folder restrictions. It's all about the css and js files that are served from there. Check your WMT again to be sure.